# docker-machine virtualbox image locations on OSX

Tags: macos, docker, docker-machine

I am using docker-machine on OSX (Mac Book) and it places the images in `~/.docker/machine`. My drive is almost full and I want to move the images to a different drive. It would be nice if there was an installation option or way to specify a different location for `.docker` and the sub directories.

Does anyone no of an easy way to do this?

Comment: You could make a symlink...

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using the `MACHINE_STORAGE_PATH` environment variable or by specifying one of `-s, --storage-path`:

```bash
$ export MACHINE_STORAGE_PATH=/Volumes/Drobo/machine
$ mkdir $MACHINE_STORAGE_PATH
$ docker-machine create test -d virtualbox
Creating CA: /Volumes/Drobo/machine/certs/ca.pem
Creating client certificate: /Volumes/Drobo/machine/certs/cert.pem
Image cache does not exist, creating it at /Volumes/Drobo/machine/cache...
No default boot2docker iso found locally, downloading the latest release...
Downloading https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases/download/v1.8.1/boot2docker.iso to /Volumes/Drobo/machine/cache/boot2docker.iso...
Creating VirtualBox VM...
Creating SSH key...
Starting VirtualBox VM...
Starting VM...
To see how to connect Docker to this machine, run: docker-machine env test
$
$ ls -l /Volumes/Drobo/machine/machines/
total 0
drwx------  13 brianz  staff  442 Aug 28 16:37 test
```

Comment: Almost works but get Unexpected error getting machine url: exit status 255 when I try to set env - same error as with symlink - must be something with my drive or permissions - I can pull up the VM in Virtual Box and it is running - Just can't access it